# Android View.GONE accessibility talkback bug

Tags: android, accessibility

This is the weirdest bug I have ever came across so far. Suppose you have a view right below the action bar (any view). If I set the view to GONE, for some reason you cannot navigate backwards towards the action bar using swipe navigation (talkback). If I set it to invisible or visible, then backwards navigation works fine, and you can get reach the action bar going backwards. Why would View.GONE ever cause something like this?

Comment: Check your logcat, maybe you call that object on OnBackPressed

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira It's not on backPressed, I'm swiping for nagivation. Swiping left puts accessibility focus on previous element and swiping right puts focus on next element, etc.